# Java txt loading code doesnt work and i dont know why

Tags: java, textbox, loading

```
JFileChooser ch = new JFileChooser();
    if(ch.showOpenDialog(this)==JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION){
        try{
            File file = ch.getSelectedFile();
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file.getPath()));
            while(br.readLine() != null){
                textArea1.setText(br.readLine());
                textArea1.setText("\n");
            }
        }catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {}catch (IOException ex) {}
    }
```

So I wanted to make program for my class in which I will load txt data from the file I will choose and I will write it in textbox and then I will proceed it. But I failed. I have no idea why but it displays me nothing in textbox. 
Also I would like to transfer the code to table and edit it and save it afterwards. But i failed with that also.

Answer (score 2):

You should collect the text you wish to display into a `StringBuilder` and then display it:

```
String line = null;
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
while((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
    sb.append(line);
    sb.append("\n");
}
textArea1.setText(sb.toString());
```